# How can I make LaTeX to recognize spaces in my macro (catcode 10)?

Tags: catcodes

I've been messing with TeX primitives, particularly catcodes, to handle diverse LaTeX situations (and to extend my wings).

I created a token gobbler with the help of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33536/13552

Why can't I see any 10s in my list of category codes?

Would it be safe to test for `\@empty` and if true, use
`\g@addto@macro{\tempa}{\fbox{ }}%`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\scanfunction#1{#1}% Don't know why this is here
\let\tempa\@empty
\def\scan@letters#1#2{% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33536/13552
   \bgroup\catcode`\ \active \let\ \fbox{ }\egroup%Try changing space to visible box
   \def\getcategory##1{\the\catcode`##1}% ` changes char into ASCI number required for \catcode
   \def\currcatcode{\getcategory{#1}}% put everything into unified token for \if
   \currcatcode, % spurious space intentional % first character missing
   \if 10\currcatcode%
     \fbox{#2}% if catcode 10 fed, print it as a box
   \fi
   \g@addto@macro{\tempa}{#1\hskip 0pt plus 1sp minus 1sp}%
   \ifx#2\@empty%\@empty is what the end of the line will look like ^^M?
   \else
     \expandafter\scan@letters % recall yourself using #2 until this conditional becomes true
   \fi
#2}

\def\scan#1{%
  %\catcode"0020 11 % Tried changing space to catcode 11
  %\the\catcode"0020 % Test to ensure change happened
  \scan@letters #1\@empty
}

\makeatother
\scan{  mac::exception  ==  }
% \scan{     } % crashes with "Improper alphabetic constant."
\begin{itemize}
  \item \tempa
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Of course, I expect the following from `\scan{  mac::exception  ==  }`

```
10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 10, 10, 12, 12, 10, 10,
```

[image]

## My Favorites for Reference

Obviously, it *is* possible to see 10.

```
\the\catcode`\
```

result: 13 (mistakenly expected 10)

```
\the\catcode`\ %
```

result: 10

```
\the\catcode"0020
```

result: 10

- [Test whether a token is a control sequence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21466/test-if-token-is-a-control-sequence/21469)

---

## 24.06.2016 Update with Practical Solution

This is perhaps useful to know, so I'm putting it here. Using the context and David Carlisle's answer to understand `\afterassignment` so that I could test for category 10 (space), I modified my code to add glue after every non-space character such that the LaTeX line-breaking mechanism would trigger when

- the total width of all character boxes = `\textwidth`

## Sample

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\macmonofont{Inconsolatazi4-Regular.otf}
%\makeatletter % or \catcode"0040=11
\def\macmono#1{\xscan#1\relax}% calls xscan which looks ahead one token, #1
\def\xscan{\afterassignment\xxscan\let\token= }% assign single token to \token and call \xxscan
\def\xxscan{%
\macmonofont% apply mono font
\ifx\token\relax\normalfont\else%test for end-of-line or end of group and switch back to normal font
  \ifcat\token\space%
    \token% token is catcode 10
    \spaceskip=.5em% remove glue from space for fixed-width space
    \xspaceskip=.5em% remove glue from space for fixed-width space
  \else%
    \token\hskip 0pt plus 1sp minus 1sp % add glue to any non-catcode 10 (space)
   \fi
\expandafter\xscan
\fi}
%\makeatother % or \catcode"0040=12
\parindent=0pt % remove firstpar autoindent
\obeylines% insert \par after each end-of-line (^^M)

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\item Some random error created by C++: \macmono{mac::IOException [File: sharecpp/trunk/PROJECTS/SpecialOps/B/Build/Implementation/Library/GenerateDocumentation.cpp, Line: 999]
    Found documentation overview begin marker more than once in DocumentationManual!
mac::IOException [File: sharecpp/trunk/PROJECTS/SpecialOps/B/Build/Implementation/Library/DocumentationThread.cpp, Line: 934]
    Processing of DocumentationManual failed while generating DocumentationOverview!} and some trailing test to make sure font changing works.  \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

## Output

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An unbraced catcode 10 character is never taken as an undelimited argument so that you can go

```
\def\foo#1#2#3{...}
\foo a b c
```

and have a, b and c (rather than the spaces between them) be the three arguments.

The usual solution is to use `\futurelet` (or as below `\afterassignment` and `\let`) but it depends what you want to do.

Your catcode changes such as

```
\catcode`\ \active
```

have no effect as the spaces have already been tokenized in the argument to your `\scan` macro.

> 10, 10,

Also you should not expect consecutive 10 even if you fixed the scanner as any number of consecutive spaces in the input file are tokenized to a single catcode 10 token

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\scan#1{\xscan#1\relax}
\def\xscan{\afterassignment\xxscan\let\tmp= }
\def\xxscan{%
\ifx\tmp\relax\else
\ifcat\tmp\space10 \else
\ifcat\tmp a11 \else
\ifcat\tmp 112 \else%...
\fi\fi\fi
\expandafter\xscan
\fi}



\begin{document}

\scan{  mac::exception  ==  }

\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, that helps. What I wanted to do is add glue to each character, except I noticed that the spaces get gobbled up (or the existing glue expands as far as possible before line breaking effectively removing visible interword spaces). I wanted to define the space to have a fixed width to ensure they exist even when allowing LaTeX to line break anywhere. First I figured I should understand why my 10s are not showing up.

Comment: @macmadness86 See I added some code, but for the use case in your comment, don't do _any_ of this! just set `\spaceskip` and `\xspaceskip` to fixed lengths.

Comment: Haha, well it was fun doing this experiment anyway. I tried doing `\spaceskip=10pt \xspaceskip=10pt` for an obvious effect and in seemed to have not effect. I am trying to be mindful of scopes. Also, if your scanner encounters any of the other catcodes, they won't show up I think.

Comment: Duh, it is not working because I am eating up all of the spaces in my original code. I should probably fix that first before complaining :) It is just hard to figure out because the only thing similar to my original code is `\scan{  mac::exception  ==  }`

Comment: I understand basically what you're doing with `\afterassignment`: "read the first token after this macro and put it in \tmp; then do \xscan." (from https://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#afterassignment-rp)

Comment: @macmadness86 other catcodes oh sure i just got bored I just test 1 for 12 and a for 11 but you can add ^ & etc to test the other codes (and add some \noexpand to take care of active characters.

Comment: I think this is my favorite thing I've learned on this site thus far. :) At first glance, `\afterassignment` didn't seem useful, but now I understand why. Also, couldn't I just automate the rest of the catcodes like I did in question (if space is the only "weird" one due to it being the arg delimiter--therefore ignored)?

Comment: @macmadness86 with let you can also detect `{` and `}` (catcode 1 and 2) which you can not get with a macro argument, by the time you have used the above to get catcode 1,2,10, you may as well use it for all of them:-)