# Plain TeX macro with float calculation

Tags: macros, tex-core

I am trying to take this TeX snippet and use it as the basis for a macro.

```
\centerline{\def\epsfsize#1#2{0.7#1} \epsfbox{1.01couet.eps}}
```

I am struggling with a bit that is required because I am actually redefining a macro that populates a rather large project.  What I thought I could do is something like the following:

```
\def\myfig#1#2#3#4{\dimen1=#4 \divide\dimen1 by 1000
\centerline{\def\epsfsize#1#2{{#4}{#1}} \epsfbox{#3}}}
```

This is clearly incorrect, probably is several ways.  I need to take argument #4 and divide it by 1000 to use as the scale (the 0.7 is the previous snippet).  I understand dimen1 is not usable for dimensionless quantities but I can't find any documentation related to such a topic.

Note that the first two arguments would go unused for the time being.

Is there a good document that covers this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have `1.01couet.eps` on my system. But every more recent TeX distribution has `example-image-a.eps`.

Therefore in the code-snippets below I will use the latter. ;-)

If I got you right, `\myfig`'s fourth argument denotes whatsoever factor.
That factor shall be divided by 1000(decimal).
The result thereof shall be passed as scale-factor into the definition of `\epsfsize`?

You can do the calculation by means of dimensions. The point is:

`\the\dimension1` yields the value held in dimension-register 1 based on the unit `pt`.

E.g., `\the\dimension1` → `30.74pt`.

Therefore do the calculation in terns of `pt`, and when it comes to using the result not as dimension but as number, strip off the phrase `pt`.

The results will not be very precise with this method of calculating.

Probably one of the packages [fp](https://ctan.org/pkg/fp) or [pgf](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) (pgf's mathematical engine) is of interest to you.

Does the snippet below provide more or less correct scale-factors for `\epsfsize` ?

```
\input epsf.tex

\long\def\PassFirstToSecond#1#2{#2{#1}}%
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}%

\begingroup
\catcode `P=12  % 
\catcode `T=12  %
\lowercase{%
  \def\x{%
    \def\RomannumeralDrivenRempt##1.##2PT{%
      0\ifnum##2>0 \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
      { ##1.##2}{ ##1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\endgroup\x%
\def\RomannumeralDrivenStrippt{\expandafter\RomannumeralDrivenRempt\the}%

\def\myfig#1#2#3#4{%
  \begingroup
  \dimen1=#4pt %
  \dimen1=.001\dimen1 %
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\centerline\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral\RomannumeralDrivenStrippt\dimen1 ##1%
    }{\def\epsfsize##1##2}%
    %%%
    \show\epsfsize
    %%%
    \epsfbox{#3}%
  }%
}%

\myfig{Unused 1}{Unused 2}{example-image-a.eps}{1000}

\myfig{Unused 1}{Unused 2}{example-image-a.eps}{700}

\myfig{Unused 1}{Unused 2}{example-image-a.eps}{200}

\myfig{Unused 1}{Unused 2}{example-image-a.eps}{40}

\bye
```

---

---

Here is the same code with a bit of explanation:

I assume this is where `\epsfsize` and `\epsfbox` come from:

```
\input epsf.tex
```

Put the first argument nested in braces behind the second argument—this way the tokens that form the first argument can be turned into arguments of the tokens that form the second argument:

```
\long\def\PassFirstToSecond#1#2{#2{#1}}%
```

Select the first of two arguments:

```
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}%
```

Select the second of two arguments:

```
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}%
```

Above I wrote: "*...do the calculation in terns of `pt`, and when it comes to using the result not as dimension but as number, strip off the phrase `pt`*".  The problem is that with `\the\dimen1` → `30.74pt` the character tokens that form the phrase `pt` will not be of category-code 11(letter) but of category-code 12(other). So we need to get `p` of category-code-12 and `t` of  category-code-12 into the code while also having these characters available in category-code 11 so they can be used within macro-names. So within a group temporarily change the category-codes of the uppercase-variants of these characters to 12. From these uppercase-variants you get the lowercase-variants in category-code 12 via `\lowercase`.

```
\begingroup
\catcode `P=12  % 
\catcode `T=12  %
\lowercase{%
  \def\x{%
    \def\RomannumeralDrivenRempt##1.##2PT{%
      0\ifnum##2>0 \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
      { ##1.##2}{ ##1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\expandafter\endgroup\x%
```

With the above the definition of `\x` will be

```
\def\x{%
    \def\RomannumeralDrivenRempt##1.##2pt{%
      0\ifnum##2>0 \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
      { ##1.##2}{ ##1}%
    }%
}%
```

, but the characters `pt` behind `##2` that delimit `##2` will be of category-code 12(other).

Therefore after expanding `\x` the definition of `\RomannumeralDrivenRempt` will be

```
\def\RomannumeralDrivenRempt#1.#2pt{%
  0\ifnum#2>0 \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
  { #1.#2}{ #1}%
}%
```

, with the characters `pt` behind `#2` that delimit `#2` of category-code 12(other). (As `\x` is defined inside the group, it needs to be expanded before ending the group, but in a way where the tokens delivered by `\x` appear behind the token `\endgroup` that ends the group. That's what `\expandafter` in `\expandafter\endgroup\x` is for.)

At first glimpse the definition looks weird. But if `\RomannumeralDrivenRempt` is preceded by `\romanumeral` and trailed by something like `400.23pt`, you get the following:

```
\romannumeral\RomannumeralDrivenRempt400.23pt
```

This in turn yields:

Step 1:

```
% romannumeral-expansion in progress
\RomannumeralDrivenRempt400.23pt
```

Step 2:

```
% romannumeral-expansion in progress
0\ifnum23>0 \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
{ 400.23}{ 400}%
```

Step 3:

```
% romannumeral-expansion in progress
% \romannumeral finds the digit 0 and keeps searching for more digits
% or a space-token that terminates the number and gets discarded.
\ifnum23>0 \expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
{ 400.23}{ 400}%
```

Step 4:  The `\ifnum`-comparison yields the "true" branch:

```
% romannumeral-expansion in progress
% \romannumeral found the digit 0 and keeps searching for more digits
% or a space-token that terminates the number and gets discarded.
\expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi
{ 400.23}{ 400}%
```

Step 5:  `\expandafter` "hits" the else-branch and the else-branch gets removed:

```
% romannumeral-expansion in progress
% \romannumeral found the digit 0 and keeps searching for more digits
% or a space-token that terminates the number and gets discarded.
\firstoftwo
{ 400.23}{ 400}%
```

Step 6:  `\firstoftwo` fetches the first argument:

```
% romannumeral-expansion in progress
% \romannumeral found the digit 0 and keeps searching for more digits
% or a space-token that terminates the number and gets discarded.
<space token>400.23
```

Step 7: Now `\romannumeral` "finds" the space-token. The space-token is taken for the terminator of the digit-sequence which forms the number which `\romannumeral` shall convert to roman notation. That terminator gets discarded and the digit-sequence that `\romannumeral` shall take for the number to convert consists only of the digit `0` while `0` is not a positive number while `\romannumeral` handles non-positive numbers as follows: It just swallows them without delivering any token in return:

```
% romannumeral-expansion done. \romannumeral found the non-positive
% number 0 and silently swallowed it without delivering any token
% in return:
400.23
```

Now let's continue with the code:

Above I wrote: "*But if `\RomannumeralDrivenRempt` is preceded by `\romanumeral` and trailed by something like `400.23pt`, you get the following:...*"  So a mechanism is needed which provides that trailing phrase:

```
\def\RomannumeralDrivenStrippt{\expandafter\RomannumeralDrivenRempt\the}%
```

(With the definition above

```
\romannumeral\RomannumeralDrivenStrippt\dimen1
```

yields:

Step 1:

```
%\romannumeral-expansion in progress
\RomannumeralDrivenStrippt\dimen1
```

Step 2:

```
%\romannumeral-expansion in progress
\expandafter\RomannumeralDrivenRempt\the\dimen1
```

Step 3:    \expandafter "hits" \the

```
%\romannumeral-expansion in progress
\RomannumeralDrivenRempt400.23pt
```

This is step 1 of the expansion-chain of `\RomannumeralDrivenRempt`.

)

Now let's continue with the code:

```
\def\myfig#1#2#3#4{%
  \begingroup
  \dimen1=#4pt %
  \dimen1=.001\dimen1 %
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\centerline\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral\RomannumeralDrivenStrippt\dimen1 ##1%
    }{\def\epsfsize##1##2}%
    %%%
    \show\epsfsize
    %%%
    \epsfbox{#3}%
  }%
}%

\myfig{Unused 1}{Unused 2}{example-image-a.eps}{1000}

\myfig{Unused 1}{Unused 2}{example-image-a.eps}{700}

\myfig{Unused 1}{Unused 2}{example-image-a.eps}{200}

\myfig{Unused 1}{Unused 2}{example-image-a.eps}{40}

\bye
```

Let's exhibit the expansion-chain with

```
\myfig{Unused 1}{Unused 2}{example-image-a.eps}{700}
```

Step 1:

```
  \begingroup
  \dimen1=700pt %
  \dimen1=.001\dimen1 %
  \expandafter\endgroup
  \expandafter\centerline\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\PassFirstToSecond\expandafter{%
      \romannumeral\RomannumeralDrivenStrippt\dimen1 ##1%
    }{\def\epsfsize##1##2}%
    %%%
    \show\epsfsize
    %%%
    \epsfbox{example-image-a.eps}%
  }%
```

Step 2: Inside the group perform temporary assignments to `\dimen1` and do "`\expandafter`-hopping" in order to get the tokens that form the expansion of `\romannumeral\RomannumeralDrivenStrippt\dimen1`  as explained above behind the token `\endgroup` which closes the group:

```
  \begingroup
  \dimen1=700pt %
  \dimen1=.001\dimen1 %
  \endgroup
  \centerline{%
    \PassFirstToSecond{%
      .7##1%
    }{\def\epsfsize##1##2}%
    %%%
    \show\epsfsize
    %%%
    \epsfbox{example-image-a.eps}%
  }%
```

The things inside the group reach TeX's stomach and get digested. The interesting remainder is:

```
  \centerline{%
    \PassFirstToSecond{%
      .7##1%
    }{\def\epsfsize##1##2}%
    %%%
    \show\epsfsize
    %%%
    \epsfbox{example-image-a.eps}%
  }%
```

Step 3: Due to `\PassFirstToSecond` this is something like:

```
  \centerline{%
    \def\epsfsize##1##2{.7##1}%
    %%%
    \show\epsfsize
    %%%
    \epsfbox{example-image-a.eps}%
  }%
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you!!  I think you understand question exactly.  I will also look into fp!

Comment: @Kevin There's also `xfp` (which is a wrapper around the LaTeX3 FPU). See a comparison [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/463558/134574).

Comment: OK.  This is useful and very interesting to me.  While helping with this plain TeX project, I have become much more interested in plain TeX myself.  I am still trying to fully understand the details of Ulrich's macro and I think it is something that I would like to become more skillful.  Is there a good resource for plain TeX macros?  I have the TeXBook on the way but, perhaps, there is something just focussed on macro "tips".

Comment: @Kevin I added some explanation to the code. I hope this helps understanding how things work...

Comment: resources for plain TeX macros: [Dr. Christian Feuersänger: Notes On Programming in TeX](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/TeX-programming-notes.pdf)/[Overleaf:How Tex macros actually work](https://de.overleaf.com/learn/latex/How%20TeX%20macros%20actually%20work:%20Part%201)/[Around the bend: A collection of TeX challenges by Michael Downes](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/challenges/AroBend/AroundTheBend.pdf)/German language: [David Kastrup: De Ore Leonis - Makroexpansion für Virtuosen](https://www.yumpu.com/de/document/view/36550731/david-kastrup-de-ore-leonis-makroexpansion-fa-1-4-r-virtuosen/3)

Comment: @Kevin resources (also) for plain TeX macros - some self-promotion: [Character bytes and character tokens: If newlines are converted to spaces, then where does catcode 5 come into the picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/349617/118714) / [How can I know the number of expandafters when appending to a csname macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/339782/118714) / [How does TeX look for delimited arguments?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438600/118714) / [What is the difference between 'macro' and 'command'?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/468661/118714)

Comment: @Kevin resources (also) for plain TeX macros - some self-promotion: [Source Code Indentation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444717/118714)

Comment: Hi Ulrich.  You came through again.  I don't read German but the 1st (Dr. Christian Feuersänger) and 3rd (Michael Downes) PDFs look perfect.  HopefullyI would be able to help others down the road. -Kev